# Parsing multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have been attempting to organize and analyze a large amount of data in an array. However, my code does not appear to be functioning the way that I would like.

I am attempting to use arrays A (Data Array) and B (Reference Array) to output one reusable array, C.

Input arrays:

```
A = [1 A B, 1 C D, 1 E F, 4 A B, 4 C D, 4 E F, 7 A B, 7 C D, 7 E F]

B = [1, 4, 7]
```

Output (Reusable) array:

```
C = [1 A B, 1 C D, 1 E F] after clearing, this array becomes

C = [4 A B, 4 C D, 4 E F] after clearing, this array becomes

C = [7 A B, 7 C D, 7 E F]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#Creating the Reference Array. This works perfectly.
B = []
keywords = open("source.txt", 'r')
for line in keywords:
    if "1" in line or "4" in line or "7" in line:
    reference = line.split()
    rowName = reference[0]
    if rowName not in B:
        B.append(rowName)

#Creating reusable array. Does not work very well.
A = []
C = []
with open("source.txt", 'r') as temp:
    for line in temp:
        A.append(line)
for item in B:
    for item in line in A:
        print line
        C.append(line)
        print C
        del C[:]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your `A`, `B` & `C` are _lists_ (Python also has array objects that are a little different, and there are also Numpy arrays). As currently written, your `A` and `C` aren't valid Python. It looks like they're supposed to contain strings, so you should fix that. This task would be simpler using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: `for item in line in A` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Fine, valid syntax that doesn't do at all what was intended here.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon It's not exactly a syntax error. `line` contains a string. `item in line in A` is equivalent to `(item in line) and (line in A)`, which evaluates to a boolean (`True` or `False`), so `for item in line in A:` raises `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Agreed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the unifying characteristic is that the first field is the same for each go around of C, and making up my own data file:

```
source.txt:
1 A B
1 C D
1 E F
4 A B
4 C D
4 E F
7 A B
7 C D
7 E F
```

We can build the groups as we go, reading the file only once:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

lines = (line.strip().split() for line in open('source.txt'))
for leadingitem, group in groupby(lines, itemgetter(0)):
    C = list(group)
    print(C)
```

The output is

```
[['1', 'A', 'B'], ['1', 'C', 'D'], ['1', 'E', 'F']]
[['4', 'A', 'B'], ['4', 'C', 'D'], ['4', 'E', 'F']]
[['7', 'A', 'B'], ['7', 'C', 'D'], ['7', 'E', 'F']]
```

Comment: Thanks for doing a `groupby` answer. I was going to do one after the OP fixed up their sample data... :)

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just use `filter` for this?

Given:

```
>>> A = ['1 A B', '1 C D', '1 E F', '4 A B', '4 C D', '4 E F', '7 A B', '7 C D', '7 E F']
```

You can filter by the beginning element of the string:

```
>>> filter(lambda s: s[0]=='1', A)
['1 A B', '1 C D', '1 E F']
>>> filter(lambda s: s[0]=='4', A)
['4 A B', '4 C D', '4 E F']
>>> filter(lambda s: s[0]=='7', A)
['7 A B', '7 C D', '7 E F']
```

Or,

```
>>> for e in ('1', '4', '7'):
...    print filter(lambda s: s.startswith(e), A)
... 
['1 A B', '1 C D', '1 E F']
['4 A B', '4 C D', '4 E F']
['7 A B', '7 C D', '7 E F']
```

Comment: The example I provided might give off that impression but the amount of data that I'm working with is massive and hard coding every filter would be very inefficient.

Comment: You don't have to hard code the filter. I am just showing an example of it's use.